# Scala.js platform dependent method implementations (or dependency injection)

Tags: scala.js

*tl;dr: how libraries like scalajs-java-time replace dependencies?*

I ran into this dependency injection with Scala.js:

In shared code:

```
object Example {
  def method(...) = { ... dependsOnPlatform ... }
  val dependsOnPlatform = ???
}
```

The naive way of doing this would be:

```
val dependsOnPlatform = if(onJS) jsImplementation else jvmImplementaion
```

The problem is that one often cannot compile `jsImplementation` for the JVM because it depends on Scala.js classes; and one might not be able to complete `fastOptJS` of the `jvmImplementaion` if it uses reflection or refers to Java classes.

Given that `object Example` must be static, one cannot use constructor injection.

It would be easy to solve the problem with reflection, but again that is not allowed in Scala.js.
It could be solved though side-effecting, but since the object is static, that would be fragile.
The dependency could be an implicit parameter of `method`, but that will require extra imports.
And this is not the kind of problem macros can solve without convoluting the build process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use a top-level object that is implemented differently in `js/src/` than in `jvm/src/`, but exposes the same interface to both. That object's API can then be normally used from `shared/src/` code. This object is typically called `Platform` and made package-private.

`js/src/.../Platform.scala`

```
package foo

private[foo] object Platform {
  def dependsOnPlatform(...) = {
    jsImplementation
  }
}
```

`jvm/src/.../Platform.scala`

```
package foo

private[foo] object Platform {
  def dependsOnPlatform(...) = {
    jvmImplementation
  }
}
```

`shared/src/.../Platform.scala`

```
package foo

object Example {
  def method(...) = {
    ...
    Platform.dependsOnPlatform(...)
    ...
  }
}
```

There is no need to use an ugly "shadowing" hack nor to write .java source files, as described in @acdenh's answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that shadowing thing is unnecessary while debugging a faulty CrossProject build.

The thing I was missing is that shared code need not be able to compile separately. I blame much of my confusing on this CrossProject system; having finally read though its source code, it became clear just how simple the setup really is.

Comment: do you know how to make this IDE-friendly? IntelliJ for example doesn't "see" the `Platform` implementations and marks the code as red. I suspect this would need some SBT setting to add the dependency when importing but maybe there's something else ...

Answer (score 0):

*The correct solution is creating a Java class and "shadowing" it with a Scala.js class.*

In shared code:

```
val dependsOnPlatform = new Injection

class InjectionForJVM { ... } //InjectionForJVM.scala

public class Injection extends InjectionForJVM { } //Injection.java
```

Then in the Scala.js part of your project:

```
class Injection { ... } //Injection.scala
```

Both of those `Injection` classes must be in the same package and have the same interface.
Do not wrap `InjectionForJVM.scala` inside any object or class, because `Injection.java` might not compile correctly. `InjectionForJVM.scala` can use both reflection and Java methods, because the class will be unreachable by `fastOptJS`. One could also implement `Injection.java` directly in Java, but who could possibly want to do that?

(to be precise, this is not really shadowing, because `Injection.java` would not exist for Scala.js in any case. Actual shadowing of classes on the JVM is possible but generally is not advisable.)